# CSS : Button is shifing bit downward as compared to label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using 
[github link](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design)

HTML Code

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    Processing
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

```
.btn { 
   position: relative; 
   padding: 8px 30px; 
   border: 0; 
   margin: 10px 1px; cursor: pointer; 
   border-radius: 2px; 
   text-transform: uppercase; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.84); 
   transition: background-color 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.28s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1); outline: none !important; }
```

You can clearly notice that button is going down as compared to label.

Any CSS Fix? temporary may be??

Comment: Add some CSS code related to it.

Comment: actually there is no custom css. I am using https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `middle vertical-align` and a `display` of `inline-block` should fix this.

### [Booply](http://www.bootply.com/JibaEZQCMI)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-2 vcenter">
    Processing
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 vcenter">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
  </div>
</div>

.vcenter {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Where are your hands man?? Just wanna kiss them brilliant bro.. :*

Comment: Its working without `vertical-align` but not without `float` and `inline-block`